# How to pass control from one controller to other in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I have one controller called *Page_controller* and another one called *Categories_controller*. Now whenever the *home* method in the *Page_controller* is called I wanna be redirected to the a´categories controller, as I wanna control the Category view from that moment on. This is what I have written:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  @categories = Category.all
  redirect_to category_url(@category)
end
end
```

but I get an error when I open the server saying:

```
undefined method `category_url' for #<PagesController:0x000000000b24ce20>
```

for the line:

```
redirect_to category_url(@category)
```

Does anyone know how I could pass control from one controller to the other? I am really desperate so apreciate any help you can provide

EDIT: this is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  #resources :categories
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'index', to: 'controller_category#index'

  devise_for :users
end
```

And the routes printed out from the console:

```
C:\Users\andri\Desktop\proj>bundle exec rake routes
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                 comments GET    /comments(.:format)                                                                      comments#index
                          POST   /comments(.:format)                                                                      comments#create
              new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)                                                                  comments#new
             edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             comments#edit
                  comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#show
                          PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#update
                          PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#update
                          DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#destroy
                     root GET    /                                                                                        pages#home
                    index GET    /index(.:format)                                                                         controller_category#index
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
            user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
        user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Comment: What does your `routes.rb` look like? Does it define the route you want to use?

Comment: @lurker I edited my question so you can see it!

Comment: Do a bundle exec rake routes and paste the output of that in your question. On the other hand, you can use the `as` option argument to add an alias to any route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncomment this line in your routes.rb file:

```
#resources :categories
```

That will define a set of routes for categories, which will provide you with methods such as `category_url(category)`.

You'll also need a CategoriesController, otherwise your next problem will be that the redirect produces an error (no such controller). And you'll need to implement `CategoriesController#show`.

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
and https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html